# How to get a json response from server using volley in android?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a login activity that receives an email and password and returns a token in this format.

```
{
"token":"your_token_here"    
}
```

I have already implemented the post request and it works. On the log I can see it. My question is how do I read this as a json object and save it into shared preferences? I also have other responses if the login is not correct but they are not status codes.
For example:

```
{
"non_field_errors":"credentials not provided"
}
```

How do I get these responses so that I can show them on a dialog.

Comment: This may help  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Answer (score 1):

if you are using POST

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("key","value"); // Request parameters to be send with post request
RequestQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    "url",
    obj , // the request body, which is a JsonObject otherwise null
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

String token = response.optString("token");
      }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

// Handle error here
      }
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

use volley' s `JsonObjectRequest`.

```
RequestQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,
    "your url",
    null, // the request body, which is a JsonObject
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
          // ok, do your job
      }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          // fail, you may need to get the error response body if the server return http status code >= 400 when request fail
      }
    }
));
```

Comment: I am already using a  string request for posting. Now when I get a response here `public void onResponse(String response) {}` how do I get the token I am looking for?

Comment: simply use ``JsonObject json = new JsonObject(response)``, but you should be use the JsonObjectRequest approach anyway.